# How can I return the result of a user selection via a tkinter dialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to write a function that creates a tkinter dialog which presents the user with a series of selection options and requires them to select one. My issue I have is that when I press the button to close the dialog my program just hangs and doesn't proceed to the next step. I get no error message to help me debug.

Please see my code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Option():
    """
    Dumnmy class for user option
    """
    def __init__(self, display_name, item_name):
        self.DisplayName = display_name
        self.ItemName = item_name

def user_selection(options):
    """
    Tkinter popup to make the user choose from a list of options
    Doesn't work - crashes on exit
    """
    tk_root = tk.Tk()
    selection = tk.StringVar()
    selection.set("1") # initial value

    for option in options:
        radio = tk.Radiobutton(tk_root, text=option.DisplayName, value=option.ItemName, var=selection)
        radio.pack()
    button = tk.Button(tk_root, text='OK', command=tk_root.destroy)
    button.pack()

    tk_root.mainloop()
    user_choice = selection.get()
    return user_choice

avaliable_options = [Option('Apple', 'apple_url'), Option('Banana', 'banana_url')]
selection = user_selection(avaliable_options)
print(selection)
```

I've exhausted my Google-foo on this one, can anyone advise what I've done wrong?

Comment: You can't acces `selection.get()` after `.destroy()`, save it before. Relevant [tkinter-dialog-windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: you could add real data in `[list of options]` so we could run it.

Comment: if I put some data in `[list of options]` and use `print(selection)` then it works for me. Maybe you get some error message in console/terminal for different part of code.

Comment: if you run it with other problem then problem can be that you use `Tk()` to create second window - it should be used to create only main window. For other windows use `Toplevel()`. OR problem can be second `mainloop()`. Tkinter should use only one `mainloop()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, they've helped me to troubleshoot.By adding in a dummy [list of options] my code worked, which surprised me. It turned out my problem was an earlier point in the program I was using another Tk() to generate a file dialog and wasn't properly destroying after use. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I have chacked your code and the problem is easy: you have to put the mainloop at the end of program, because when the compiler read these function, it doesn't compile the next code. But you can make a similar effect if you use a update function to the root.
So the code changed is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Option():
    """
    Dumnmy class for user option
    """
    def __init__(self, display_name, item_name):
        self.DisplayName = display_name
        self.ItemName = item_name

def user_selection(options):
    """
    Tkinter popup to make the user choose from a list of options
    Doesn't work - crashes on exit
    """
    tk_root = tk.Tk()
    selection = tk.StringVar()
    selection.set("1") # initial value

    for option in options:
        radio = tk.Radiobutton(tk_root, text=option.DisplayName, value=option.ItemName, var=selection)
        radio.pack()
    button = tk.Button(tk_root, text='OK', command=tk_root.destroy)
    button.pack()

    tk_root.update()
    user_choice = selection.get()
    return user_choice

avaliable_options = [Option('Apple', 'apple_url'), Option('Banana', 'banana_url')]
selection = user_selection(avaliable_options)
print(selection)

tk_root.mainloop()
```